# placeholder div in IE not work (the cursor appears at the end)

Tags: html, css

The cursor is not at the beginning of the div! It appears at the end .. after the text-placeholder!

In chrome, works perfect! The cursor is at the beginning of the div, before the text-placeholder, in IE the cursor is at the end ....

```
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
```

Example --> [codepen](http://codepen.io/flesler/pen/AEIFc)

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution --> http://jsfiddle.net/1shhhn7z/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.reply-comment',function() {
var reply = $('<div class="container-reply"><div class="unselectable div-placeholder"><div class="div-placeholder2">Type a text...</div></div><div class="initial-comment"><div class="inputAddReplyComment inputADD2" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" aria-expanded="true" title="" data-placeholder="" id="" style=""></div></div></div>').insertAfter($(this).parent());


    reply.find('.div-placeholder').on('mousedown mouseup click', function(e) { reply.find('.inputAddReplyComment').focus(); });

    reply.find('.inputAddReplyComment').on('focus',function(e){
        var editable = this;
        function listener(evt) {
            if ($(this).text().length>0)
                reply.find('.div-placeholder').attr("style","display:none;");
            else reply.find('.div-placeholder').attr("style","display:show;");
        }
        if (editable.addEventListener) {                    
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1)
                editable.addEventListener("input", listener, false);
            else // The event 'input' not work in IE11 ... It has to work!! I don't know why not fire... =/
            {
                editable.addEventListener("input", listener, false);
                editable.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", listener, false);
                editable.addEventListener("DOMNodeRemoved", listener, false);
                editable.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", listener, false);                     
                editable.addEventListener("keyup", listener, false);
                editable.addEventListener("keydown", listener, false);
            }                   
        }
        e.stopPropagation();                
    });         
    reply.find('.inputAddReplyComment').focus();
return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JS:

```js
    var div=document.getElementById("div");
    function clearPlaceholder() {
      if (div.innerHTML=="Enter text here...") {
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML="";
      }
    }
    function addPlaceholder() {
      if (div.innerHTML=="") {
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML="Enter text here...";
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div contenteditable="true" onFocus="clearPlaceholder();" onFocusOut="addPlaceholder();" id="div">Enter text here...</div>
```

It works perfectly in IE and Chrome... didn't test Firefox or other browsers, but it should work on all browsers with JS enabled.

Comment: So you want it to be there until the user starts to type?

Comment: I found the solution... It was not easy to do... =/ [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1shhhn7z/1/)

Comment: Instead of that you could just add a on key press event to the above.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today too. You just need a few tweaks to make it work with IE11:

```
[contenteditable=true]:empty::after {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    display: block; /* For Firefox */
    cursor: text; /* For Chrome */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 2em;
}
[contenteditable=true] {
    position: relative;
}
```

Using absolute positioning takes it out of the flow of the document. But there were still weird effects when you typed and then backspaced all the characters, which is why I changed it to `::after`.

I also noticed that Chrome will use the normal cursor when over the placeholder, so I had to specifically tell it to use the text cursor.